# Is there a way to avoid using GAC with SSIS

Tags: ssis, gac

Coming back with a question about the GAC and SSIS.
My colleagues developped two external DLL's for their SSIS packages. I'm trying to see how it can be added to the server without being added in the GAC.

Why? Just because I prefer to keep my installation the cleaner as possible and this instance is located on a cluster so, when there is an update (or something else), the maintenance is not really easy.

Best way for me is to put these DLL's on a network shared drive where they can be accessed by SSIS. Is it possible to act like this?

Thanks!

PS: I'm working with SSIS & SQL Server 2012 on a Windows Server 2008R2 64bits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only approach I've seen used to avoid pushing things into the GAC, but still use it from within SSIS, is to roll that DLL into a service, web or windows, and then change your code to use those service methods.

The other thought is if there isn't actual code reuse for these DLLs, just have them inline them into the package. You can add classes to the Script Tasks and Component, they're just C#/VB.NET projects.